# Combine ExpressJS Router and Angular 10 Routes

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-routing, express-router

I develop web using `NodeJs` and `Angular 10`. for APIs, I used ExpressJs and frontend i used `Angular` router. i am troubling one issue. let me explain by example.

I have a route called mydomain.com/download/file -> this URL belongs to ExpressJS not connected with my frontend. I did not define this URL path in my angular app.

here my code

```
app.component.html
<a target="blank" href="http://example.com/download/file"> Watch File </a>
```

so in some case, i need to render file direct from NodeJs Server using `response.sendFile()`. in this case i need to redirect angular app to express url. but angular throw out on home page. because angular finding that path in angular routes.

how can i solve this issue? how can i render file from direct expressJs along with angular?

Comment: Please share the code which calls the download file action.

Comment: If I do refresh using ctr + shift + r then it is working. but it's not user-oriented.